# meteor mongodb limit return only id

Tags: mongodb, meteor, limit

I want to limit the number of post I get from my query

```
db.posts.find({});
```

I got all my posts. I only want the first 10 posts so I've done this.

```
db.posts.find({}, {limit: 10});
```

But instead of having 10 posts, it only return id from all my posts

Comment: What form are you getting them back in? An array of just `_id` Strings? Or something like this: `[{_id: "cZdWqpP4XsvWwCkva"},{_id: "mIxYfxadWZSc5JBdW"},...]`? How do you know you're only getting ids?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're doing this in the mongo shell rather than in your Meteor app directly. The `limit` syntax differs slightly between the two environments:

Mongo shell ([docs](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#limit-the-number-of-documents-to-return)):

```
db.posts.find().limit( 10 )
```

Meteor js:

```
posts.find({},{limit: 10});
```